# Alphabetical sorting for dropdown

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I just started working with Angular 2 and TypeScript. I'm having hard time with implementing code for it.

My question is how to do sorting option in my dropdown list?

**Here is HTML code:**

```
<div class="col-12">
    <select class="form-control" id="type" [(ngModel)]="measure" (change)="getMeasures()">
        <option *ngFor="let option of options" [ngValue]="option.measure">{{option.display}}</option>
      </select>
  </div>
```

Here is the part of my TypeScript for options:

```
    options = [
        {
          measure: 'length',
          display: 'Length'
        },
        {
          measure: 'area',
          display: 'Area'
        },
        {
          measure: 'volume',
          display: 'volume'
        },
        {
          measure: 'time',
          display: 'Time'
        },
        {
          measure: 'current',
          display: 'Current'
        },
        {
          measure: 'energy',
          display: 'Energy'
        },
        
  ]
```

Comment: Clarify your question and the problem you are facing. On which metric do you want to sort ?

Comment: @Abrar I will like to sort them when I click on dropdown so they will be in aphabetical order in my list. So first will be Area then Current etc.

Comment: @pooh098 did you check my naswer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Pipe in angular2, say **`orderBy`**,

```
<div class="col-12">
    <select class="form-control" id="type" [(ngModel)]="measure" (change)="getMeasures()">
        <option *ngFor="let option of options | orderBy : 'measure'" [ngValue]="option.measure">{{option.display}}</option>
      </select>
  </div>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/rtFzCsJCzLPgVMKfYGff?p=preview)**

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer is no longer valid. According to the docs at https://angular.io/guide/pipes

> Appendix: No FilterPipe or OrderByPipe Angular doesn't provide pipes
>   for filtering or sorting lists. Developers familiar with AngularJS
>   know these as filter and orderBy. There are no equivalents in Angular.
>
> This isn't an oversight. Angular doesn't offer such pipes because they
>   perform poorly and prevent aggressive minification. ... While some may
>   not care to minify this aggressively, the Angular product shouldn't
>   prevent anyone from minifying aggressively. Therefore, the Angular
>   team decided that everything Angular provides will minify safely.
>
> The Angular team and many experienced Angular developers strongly
>   recommend moving filtering and sorting logic into the component
>   itself.

Comment: But do you have a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Find the example given in this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/order-by-pipe?file=app%2Forder-by.pipe.ts

create a pipe order-by.pipe.ts in your application and use it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting pipe is applied see https://angular.io/guide/pipes

```
<option *ngFor="let option of options | orderBy:'measure'" [ngValue]="option.measure">{{option.display}}</option>
```